# Formula for Summing up incrementing number

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can someone help me what is the best formula for the following:
I have $25$ as a starting number and as I increment I would add $25$ to my initial no. then sum up my 1st and 2nd no. Resulting to $50$ then increment again by $25$ and summing up the results of the 1st, 2nd and 3rd no. and so on..

\begin{array}{c c c}
1 & 25 & 25\\
2 & 50 & 75\\
3 & 75 & 150\\
4 & 100 & 250
\end{array}

Comment: Welcome to Maths SE.  __2__ things: I have reformatted your post  but the input interpretation may be wrong so in future use [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?lq=1) to learn how to format via $LaTeX$ and secondly, if someone gives an answer that is useful to you don't forget to tick it. All the best.

Answer (score 4):

Let's denote the $i$-th number as $n_i$. We have 
$$ n_i = 25 \cdot 1 + 25 \cdot 2 + 25 \cdot 3 + \cdots + 25 \cdot i $$
(adding up the multiples of $25$). We know - [from Gauß or at least attributed to him](http://nzmaths.co.nz/gauss-trick-staff-seminar) - that 
$$ \sum_{k=1}^i k = 1 + 2 + \cdots + i = \frac 12 i(i+1) $$
Hence
$$ n_i = 25 \cdot (1+2+\cdots + i) = \frac{25}2 i(i+1) $$

Comment: What if you have an initial value that is not 25?.:) TIA